# How to modify SQL string in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

My code is this:

```
elseif ($criteria == 'doctoratedegree')
    $query->where('postgradcourses', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
```

So basically in the front end, a person will select "Doctorate degree" in the form drop down menu, then type the course they want to search for and the code will look for the course in the postgradcourses column of the courses database table.  problem is, the Masters degree option in the menu is coded in the same way where the code will also look in the postgradcourses column.

How can I modify the query code so that it searches for: PhD in . $searchItem . ?

Basically, the code will add a specific string along with whatever the person searched for.

Comment: You **don't** modify the SQL code. You pass through a parameter, in a prepared query. Otherwise you are open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Charlieface ok so how would I modify the above code to create a prepared query with a parameter?

Comment: @Charlieface This is parameterized. Third parameter of `where` in laravel is a value.

Comment: Maybe `elseif(in_array($criteria, array('doctoratedegree', 'phd'))) {`? Not really clear what you have and what you want.. can you add a bit more details

Comment: @user3783243 not sure what details you need. right now, the query does into the column of the table and does a search for the searchitem inputted by the user.  I want to add on the searchitem with specific text but not sure how to alter the code.

Comment: `$criteria` comes from where? `$searchItem` comes from where? What is the user's input?

Comment: @user3783243 `$criteria` comes from the drop down menu that the user selects on the search form (`name="criteria"`).  In the controller file, it gets pulled (`$criteria = $request['criteria'];`).   same with $searchItem.  the form has a text field that has `name="searchItem"` in the code.  The controller file pulls it in (`$searchItem = str_replace("%", " ", $request['searchItem']);`).

Comment: Your where clause with "LIKE %%" is correct. Show your code before where to your $query variable.

Comment: If this line 
$query->where('postgradcourses', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
is before your get or first method... try
$query = $query->where('postgradcourses', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
And after
$query = $query->get();

Comment: @NinoGiovanny what does adding get() do to the code? I want the code to add text to the searchItem string.

Comment: Question is still unclear to me so. In when does `searchItem` get the `phd`?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should differentiate between the Masters & Doctorate request.
Pass another parameter & you can switch on that basis & modify your query. This is the right thing to do.
If that's not possible somehow, then you should add an **OR** condition in your query and search for *postgradcourses* with concatenated string and this will give you both set of results post that parse that result and store PHD results in an array and Masters in another and use it as per your need.

```
$like_statement .= " postgradcourses LIKE "."'%".$keyword."%'"." OR postgradcourses LIKE "."'%".$keyword."%'";
```

Comment: My developer made the code but he went MIA and my new developer is working on some other stuff.  Having a hard time trying to figure out how to modify the code. How do I pass another parameter and modify the query?

Comment: This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: @user3783243 question: how do you know if a code is open to SQL injection?

Comment: @Thomas identifiers and values are mixed. Values should not be in a SQL string in PHP, the driver should bind them and escape them

Comment: @user3783243 values like postgradcourses?   what do you mean by values?  how do you mean by driver?  how do you bind the values and escape them?

Comment: @Thomas `postgradcourses` is a column/identifier. The `$keyword` would be a `value`. PDO or mysqli are the primary drivers, laravel uses PDO which is what you are running. Don't escape, bind. Laravel binds the third parameter of the `where` function, that is reserved for a value. I can't see a way this answer could be used with that, unless the `where`s can be daisy chained. I don't use laravel so cant advise much on that

Comment: @Thomas I just gave you an idea of how things should be. You can apply validations before. All the requests parameters which are coming from frontend has to be verified first.